# Split string on more conditions

Tags: postgresql, split

In my Postgres DB i have a column with strings like this:

```
User::CreateUserCommand
Person::UpdatePersonKommunikationCommand
```

I need to split these string as follow:

1. Everything left from **:**  (User,Person)
2. Everything after second **::** until the second uppercase comes (Create,Update)
3. Next Word with uppercase except Command (, Kommunikation)

GOAL:

- User, Create, User, NULL
- Person, Update, Person, Kommunikation

Step 1 i manage to do myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the regexp variant of `substring` to *extract* these parts of the string.

```sql
with t(txt) as
(
 values
 ('User::CreateUserCommand'),
 ('Person::UpdatePersonKommunikationCommand')
)
select 
    substring (txt from '^([^:]+)') as a,
    substring (txt from '::([A-Z][a-z]+)') as b,
    substring (txt from '::[A-Z][a-z]+([A-Z][a-z]+)') as c,
    substring (txt from '::[A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z][a-z]+([A-Z][a-z]+)(?:Command$)') as d
from t;
```

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User | Create | User |  |
| Person | Update | Person | Kommunikation |